# Handling error in Subscription in Reporting service

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report in SSRS with "Data-driven Subscription" , but sometimes there is errors like below

- Done: 10 processed of 10 total; 10 errors.
  [image]

and the reason of these errors I think network problems, ssrs can't store pdf in the network folder.

So I need a way to handle any error that happened in this stage to be able to retry again, or at least to know witch reports not generated correctly,

any Idea how can I handle these errors?

Answer (score 1):

There is no technique to error capture, you just have to carefully adjust the paremeters if you have them in the report. 
I have many years experience in making these statements, and in the beginning I had a similar problem but I solved it

Comment: Thank you, But I think I must find a solution because errors not comes from my code only but from external systems too.
I'm thinking in making a new delivery method like "Email" and "File", it will be custom code for new one, that I can handle any error on it.

Comment: references to create a new delivery method : 
Implementing the IDeliveryExtension Interface for a Delivery Extension : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154481(v=sql.100).aspx

Deploying a Delivery Extension : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153647(v=sql.100).aspx